# awk output cannot be redirect to a file

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk to fetch a few lines from a castep output file.

```
forces_line = 360
no_atom = 6
```

If I just type:

```
awk -v force_start=${forces_line} -v force_number=${no_atom} 'NR==(force_start+6), NR==(force_start+5+force_number) {print $4 "  " $5 "  " $6}' positive.castep
```

I will get:

```
-0.04628  0.00040  0.00040    
0.01782  0.00674  -0.00622    
0.01782  -0.00622  0.00674    
-0.02313  0.00622  0.00622    
0.01669  -0.00372  -0.00372    
0.01707  -0.00342  -0.00342
```

But if I rediret the result to a positive.dat file,

```
awk -v force_start=${forces_line} -v force_number=${no_atom} 'NR==(force_start+6), NR==(force_start+5+force_number) {print $4 "  " $5 "  " $6}' positive.castep > positive.dat
```

The file positive.dat is empty.

What happens?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't explain your symptom - there must be an additional factor. Is the file truly empty?. Please update _your question directly_ with additional information, and consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It may be an artifact of your question, but note that your variable assignments at the top won't work, because you have whitespace around the `=` char. So perhaps the variables are never assigned values, causing the `awk` comment not to work as expected.

Comment: also, redirection can be added to print directly... `{print $4 "  " $5 "  " $6 > "positive.dat" }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a section of a program so that I direct set values to the key variables used. There is no difference between redirection ">" and ">>" in this situation. The problem is my linux computer has run out of memory space. An external problem, not the code itself.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. This is an answer, and it is not meant to be used like this. An answer should provide a solution to your problem, which this is clearly not the case. Your added information would better fit in a comment under your original post. Moreover, the problem is not reproducible.